# Cannot use F10 in command-line applications in Pantheon Terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, command-line, pantheon-terminal

As title says - when launching "mc" in Pantheon Terminal the F10 key (used to signal "quit" for mc) is not received.

The Gnome Terminal has the option to disable the "menu shortcut key F10".

Is there a workaround or a configuration to change?

Thank you for your help!

Best regards,
SoftExpert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to use the F10 inside the terminal edit your settings.ini file  at `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and add the line:

```
gtk-menu-bar-accel=""
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This kind of works - with SHIFT + F10 mc closes without asking questions. F10 by itself has no "positive" effect - it will focus the "search" widget. I tried to unbind it by using the syntax you provided but could not make it to behave. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I think this is somehow expected behavior since in terminal applications everything with shift goes to the shell. No other suggestion. I think you have to use or dig deep into this stuff https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/937822

Comment: Sorry, I pressed Enter before finishing my comment.

Comment: I put following config: `@binding-set NoKeyboardNavigation {
    unbind "F10",
    unbind "<shift>F10"

}

* {
gtk-key-bindings: NoKeyboardNavigation
}` but F10 will still focus the "search"  widget.

Comment: I found the solution that works - at least for me: I added  `gtk-menu-bar-accel=""` in the settings.ini inside `~/.config/gtk-3.0`. Thank you @Djax - I followed your suggestion and sifting through the bugs related I found solution here [bug #661973](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=661973#c7)

Comment: how can we edit the answer so that it can be easy to read?

Comment: @SoftExpert I changed my answer to your solution. If it is ok you can accept it.

Comment: I proposed solution (for Terminal) which avoids having to mess with the gtk settings: https://github.com/elementary/terminal/pull/105

Answer (score 2):

My settings.ini was empty so I actually had to add Settings section to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini `[Settings]
gtk-menu-bar-accel=""`

Comment: Jan Klepal's answer is working. Settings section should be exist to solve this issue.

Comment: gtk-menu-bar-accel="" works but it creates lots of error messages.
gtk-menu-bar-accel= is better ie without the quotes